# C++ does not have a class type

Tags: c++, class

my code is the following

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
...

class A {
    NEW_TYPE a;
    ...
  public:
    typedef vector<int> NEW_TYPE;
    ...
}
```

error says 'NEW_TYPE' does not name a type

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You're using it before you define it.

Comment: Just add the declaration before the class definition. It doesn't necessarily need to be in the class scope.

Comment: @Comrade That doesn't seem like good advice. The semantics of having it outside the class scope are totally different. Firstly, it pollutes the global namespace unnecessarily, and further, there are many situations where a typedef in a class template depends on a template parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, names in C++ are only available for use *after* they have been declared:

```
typedef int foo;
foo x = 1;        // OK

bar y = 2;        // Error
typedef int bar;  // too late
```

The same goes for your class. Move the typedef up:

```
class A
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<int> NEW_TYPE;
private:
    NEW_TYPE a;
    // ...
public:
    // ...
};
```

Comment: so in my case I have to move the whole public section up ?

Comment: @user1464870: No, just the typedef. I added the code. (By the way, typedefs can be private, too, if you don't need to expose them.)

Comment: @user1464870: You can have as many public/protected/private sections in one class as you want. It doesn't always look pretty, though.